# Writing the output of a command to specific columns of a csv file, unix

Tags: bash, csv, unix, sed, git-bash

I wanted to write the output of command to specific columns (3rd and 5th) of the csv file.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Value,1\nCount,1" >> file.csv
echo "Header1,Header2,Path,Header4,Value,Header6" >> file.csv
sed 'y/ /,/' input.csv >> file.csv
```

**input.csv** in the above snippet will look something like this

```
1234567890 /training/folder
0325435287 /training/newfolder
```

Current output of file.csv

```
Value,1
Count,1
Header1,Header2,Path,Header4,Value,Header6
1234567890,/training/folder
0325435287,/training/newfolder
```

**Expected Output** of file.csv

```
Value,1
Count,1
Header1,Header2,Path,Header4,Value,Header6
,,/training/folder,,1234567890,
,,/training/newfolder,,0325435287,
```

Comment: Tangentially, you would generally prefer `printf` over `echo -e`, even in a Bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` instead of `sed`

```
cat input.csv | awk '{print ",," $1 "," $2 ","}' >> file.csv
```

`awk` can process a stdin input by line to line. It implements a print function and each word is processed as a argument (in your case, `$1` and `$2`). In the above example, I added `,,` and `,` as an inline argument.

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) The same logic could trivially be implemented in `sed` just as well.

Comment: @tripleee I don't know how to implement that logic using the `sed` command.

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution for me to understand. @BeardOverflow

Answer (score 3):

All the operations can be done in a single `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS=, -v pre="Value,1\nCount,1" -v hdr="Header1,Header2,Path,Header4,Value,Header6" '
   BEGIN {print pre; print hdr}
   {print "", "", $1, "", $2, ""}
' input.csv

Value,1
Count,1
Header1,Header2,Path,Header4,Value,Header6
,,i1234567890,,/training/folder,
,,0325435287,,/training/newfolder,
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you could try following code. Which is using `sed`'s capability of back reference.

```
sed -E 's/(^[^ ]*) +(.*$)/,,\2,,\1,/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `-E` option of `sed` to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) first. Then in main program using `s` option to perform substitution operation. In 1st part of substitution creating 2 back references(capability to catch values by using regex and keep them in temp buffer memory to be used later on while substituting it with in 2nd part of substitution). In 2nd part of substitution substituting whole line with 2 commas followed by 2nd capturing group`\2` followed by 2 commas followed by 1st capturing group `\1` following by `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially add empty columns as part of your `sed` script.

```
sed 'y/ /,/;s/,/,,/;s/^/,,/;s/$/,/' input.csv >> file.csv
```

This replaces the first comma with two, then adds two up front and one at the end.

Your expected output does not look like valid CSV, though. This is also brittle in that it will fail for any file names which contain a space or a comma.